# Logging Spring Sleuth Span Id of source application error channel

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have a system setup with a RabbitMQ event bus and applications using spring cloud stream. To help keep track of the messages through the system I'm also using `spring-cloud-sleuth`.

The question I have involves the errorChannel flow/binding. I'm not using the the `error` binding in my configuration (referring to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_spring_integration_error_channel_support)). Instead I have a flow setup to listen to the errorChannel, which adds an extra header to the message and then sends it off to an error destination. It looks similar to below (written in Groovy):

```
IntegrationFlows
  .from('errorChannel')
  .log()
  .handle(MessagingException, {e, h -> 
      def message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(e).copyHeaders(h).setHeader('name', 'myApp').build()
      errorSource.channel().send(message)
  .channel('nullChannel')
  .get()
```

Where `errorSource`'s channel is declared as an `@Output`.

The log line outputs something similar to:

`INFO [myApp,1234,4321,false] LoggingHandler: ErrorMessage [...]`

When I receive the message from the error destination though, the value in the `X-B3-ParentSpanId` header doesn't match the span id from the log message above (the 4321 value), or any other span ids logged within the source application.

The only way I can see a match is if I bump the logging of `org.springframework.cloud` up to DEBUG, and even then it's a log line from `TracingChannelInterceptor` (although that instance looks like it belongs to the list of interceptors for the errorChannel, so I feel like I'm close). I'd rather not leave DEBUG on as it obviously gets pretty noisy.

After all that, the question is if there is any logging I can set on the error channel or binding itself that would output some log lines with a span id that would match what is put in the `X-B3-ParentSpanId` header? The purpose is to grab that span id and save it, so later it can be used to go right to the source app when examining the logs.

We are saving the trace id as well, and I'm seeing that come through fine (and matches the source application's trace ids), but it would be helpful to have both the trace and span ids together.

Answer (score 0):

The `MessagingException` has a `failedMessage` property; you should find what you need in its headers.

Comment: In my case, the headers in `failedMessage` all have the same value in the 4 sleuth headers ("spanTraceId", "spanId", "X-B3-SpanId", "X-B3-TraceId"), and that value is just the trace ID. No unique span id value I can use.

Comment: @gary-russell - Any suggestions on what might be causing all the headers on the `failedMessage` to be the same?

Comment: I have no idea; I am not familiar with sleuth; perhaps if you add debug messages to your question showing the original message and the error message might help.